# Inputting playing card values to aneural network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, categorical-encoding

I am trying to create a NN to play a card game wherein each state is represented by the hands of 4 players. Every round, the hand of each player is decreased by 1 (discarded). Each player starts with a hand of 8 cards. I feel inclined to represent each card as a one-hot vector:

```
{1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}{1, 0, 0, 0}
value                                  suit
= [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0] for the Ace of Hearts
```

My question relates simply to how to structure the input layer/s of the NN. The order of cards within a player's hand does not matter, but the NN needs to know that a certain card belongs to a certain hand.

How do I input this encoded data to a NN. Do I need
$17(onehotcard)*8(maxcards/hand)*4(players)=544$ input neurons?

Could someone please explain the best way to input one-hot data to a NN (one neuron per binary value?) where the order of a maximum of 8 cards is irrelevant within a hand but the association of a given card to a given hand is important? Will the consistently reducing number of cards per hand (number of players is constant) be an issue?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimately, yes, if you are representing individual cards as 17-dimensional one-hot vectors and passing all four hands into the network, then you'll need a total of 544 inputs.

(An alternative might be to ignore suit in the representation, represent individual cards as 52-dimensional one-hot vectors, and represent hands as *sums* of the one-hot card vectors. Then you'd have $4(hands) * 52(hand.representation) = 208(input.neurons)$. Not saying this is necessarily better, just an option).

Anyways, the arrangement of those inputs may depend on your network structure. If you're using a feed-forward/MLP network, for example, you'd probably concatenate all the cards into a single 544-dimensional vector. But if you're using a convolutional network, you may want to want to reshape the inputs into a tensor with shape (eg) (17, 8, 4).

Comment: Would your suggestion to *represent individual cards as 52-dimensional one-hot vectors, and represent hands as sums of the one-hot card vectors* be applicable if suit was considered to be an important attribute?

Comment: It might be helpful, but may not be necessary. A network may be able to adequately capture the importance of suit in internal features without you explicitly representing suit in the input. (This is probably modulated by network depth/structure).

Comment: Great, thanks for the help. One final question: assuming that both networks were equally adept for a hand of length 8, in the next round, when the hand length reduces to a length of 7, will either model intuitively be superior? I imagine zero-padding is going to be the most appropriate means of handling this situation.

Comment: I don't have a strong intuition as to which model would be preferred to deal with shrinking hands.

For the model that represents cards individually, zero-padding would probably be the most natural choice. 

For the model that represents hands as single vectors, you wouldn't need to pad, but you may want to include something like layer normalization early in the network to keep activation magnitudes relatively stable.

Comment: If you wanted to use a convnet, you could even consider packing hands into (13, 4) matrices, with ones as indicators for a card being in the hand, and then stacking the hands together to get a (4, 13, 4) tensor. This would get you a 208-unit input that represents suit distinctly from face value. 

(I'm not sure which axes would be best to convolve on here, though).